# Why WooCommerce REST API seems not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I'm currently working on my admin website using WooCommerce REST API, It works very well since last week but now it shows error like

```
Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view]
```

I don't change anything in my code, The authentication credentials are all fine. Thanks for any advice.

**Edited:**

```
protected $url = 'https://mywebsite.com'; 
protected const CONSUMER_KEY = 'ck_b7144d17091aa01a7a096154a445180c603d****';
protected const CONSUMER_SECRET = 'cs_cdb7705d4ad5bf29aa2b6366c55ac98397e4****';

function __construct(){
    $this->woocommerce = new Woo(
        $this->url,
        self::CONSUMER_KEY,
        self::CONSUMER_SECRET,
        [
            'wp_api'  => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v2',
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is often as a result of an setup issue, specifically with what values you've passed to `verifySsl` and `queryStringAuth`. You didn't post your code, so I can't tell you specifically, but these two resources might help:

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-node/issues/43

https://robotninja.com/blog/fix-common-woocommerce-rest-api-issues/

Comment: Please see my code. I don't know how can I add that base on my code.